# Изменение состояния объекта работающего скрипта из второго скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Вопрос собственно в чем.
Есть скрипт `bot.py`, в котором есть словарь `USERS user_id :  user_class()`.
У объекта `user_class` есть параметр, допустим `A`.
Второй скрипт: `alert.py`. Запускается кроном.
Вот в этом скрипте импорчен `from bot import USERS as u`
и я пытаюсь изменить значение параметра `A` у конкретного элемента словаря `USERS`:

```
u.get(user_id).A = 5
```

Вывожу на экран первичное значение параметра, меняю, вывожу измененное.
Параметр меняется, но, на сколько я понял, только в пределах скрипта `alert`.

Как донести изменения до `USERS` в скрипте `bot.py`?

Comment: Если нужно просто общее хранилище, мб просто в базе хранить? Создадите sqlite базу, в ней заведете таблицу и оба скрипта будут в эту базу ходить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под каждый Ваш скрипт создается отдельная защищенная область памяти. Напрямую обмениваться текущими значениями переменных они не могут.

Варианты:

1. Первый скрипт выгружает значения переменных в файл, второй их считывает. Здесь Вам поможет модуль pickle, он есть в стандартной библиотеке. Еще можно выгружать нужные данные в СУБД.
2. Оба ваших скрипта запускаются из одного script.py и работают параллельно с помощью multiprocessing.Process, а обмениваются данными через multiprocessing.Queue. multiprocessing тоже входит в стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Поступил, собственно, так как Вы описали - использую БД)